# Did Shakayamuni Buddha talk about the Trikaya?

Tags: theravada, the-buddha, reference-request, trikaya

Did Shakayamuni Buddha talk about the Trikaya? If so where?
I am looking for suttas attributed to Shakyamuni in the times of Theravada.

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't explicit in the Theravada but the foundation was already there. The concept got fully developed by the time of the Mahayana. Further info. is available from the wiki page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trikaya#P.C4.81li_Canon)

Comment: Ahh.. Apparently in the Aganna Sutta "Because the titles of the Tathagatha are: The Body of Dhamma, The Body of Brahma, the Manifestation of Dhamma, and the Manifestation of Brahma."

Answer (score 0):

No but the concept of dharmakaya in Theravada is known as [dhammakaya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmak%C4%81ya).

The ideas of sambhogakaya and nirmanakaya (rupakaya) on the other hand were not developed fully until [Mahayana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trikaya#Mah.C4.81y.C4.81na) entered the picture.

According to the same Wikipedia entry, it is possible the idea of some form of rupa-kaya was taking shape though as this passage (section 9) from the [Aggañña Sutta](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/religion/f2001/edit/docs/aggannasutta.pdf) may indicate:

> "I am a true son of Blessed Lord, born of his mouth, born of Dhamma,
>   created by Dhamma, an heir of Dhamma." Why is that? Because, Vasettha,
>   this designates the Tathagata: "The Body of Dhamma", that is, "The
>   Body of Brahma", or **"Become Dhamma", that is, "Become Brahma"**."

This may be a misinterpretation of sutta taken out of context because it does not seem to be repeated through other Theravadin literatures.